# Select not null as

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-express

In an SQL query, I want to select a nullable columns as a boolean depending if it is null or not. Simple example:

```
SELECT name AS UserName, age AS UserAge, (birthday IS NOT NULL) AS HasEnteredBirthday
FROM users
```

Result:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IS'.
```

Expected result:

```
Peter 31 1
Greg  54 0
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: You can use `case`.....which database engine are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all databases support boolean types.  You can use `case` as:

```
SELECT name AS UserName, age AS UserAge,
       (CASE WHEN birthday IS NOT NULL THEN 'true' ELSE 'false' END) AS HasEnteredBirthday
FROM users;
```

Often, the integer "1" is used for true and "0" for false.

Comment: 0 and 1 is fine. I have updated the answer to reflect this. Would the query then be similar with 1 and 0 instead of true and false?

Comment: @stefan yes, it would be.